# Como usar una dependencia en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Soy algo nuevo en Node JS y no entiendo muy bien como usar una dependencia llamada [flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/) a mi documento HTML para que se agregue automaticamente sin tener que importarlo desde el mismo HTML

```
const app = express()

app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/flexboxgrid/'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile('index.html', {"root": __dirname})
})
```

Localizacion

```
node_modules
| flexboxgrid
    | css
      | flexboxgrid.min.css
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por lo que indica la [documentación](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid/blob/master/README.md#css), para usar la hoja de estilos debes incluirla en tu `html`. Como cualquier otra hoja de estilos. No comprendo realmente tu pregunta. Por cierto, la forma en que usas `static` de ExpressJS no es la más adecuada, estás dando acceso público a esa carpeta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Realmente gracias, como mencione soy novato